# How to know the disk name instead of "Eject device" on the "Safely Remove" context menu on the notification area?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, external-drive, safely-remove-hardware

If the drive has partitions that Windows can recognise, the menu displays the drive label and letter. But for disks that do not have such partitions, it just shows "Eject Device" like the screen capture below. I have multiple of such items, so I am not sure which one is which. Placing the mouse over the "Eject Device" does not show more information like the disk name. How can I "safely remove" the hard disk I want, not some other disks, when it shows no more information but "Eject Device"?

[image]

Comment: I myself hate the garbage out of this system for the same reason you bring up.  Usually.. I just *guess* based on the mounted file systems.  You and I both probably agree that this is sloppy at best.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have created a console app for this. Check out my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own console application. It is easy to use. It shows a list of the number and "friendly name" of all disks. And you just need to choose the number.

https://github.com/HubKing/EjectDisk

The source code is available there and of course, I have added a binary for 64-bit Windows, so you can just download and run it without any compilation.

Comment: Thats some nice clean code there Tex.  Simple and unbloated.  Easy enough to read that the comments aren't really needed.  Nice work.

Comment: The link to the script is dead (404)